# EntityFramework Nullable FKs for optional many-to-one relations

Tags: c#, entity-framework

This is my database:
[image: db]

What I am trying to achieve is:

- Customer -> CustomerNote is normal one to many connection, because Customer can have multi notes.
- 1 IssueLog will only have 1 Note every time, but I want to reuse CustomerNote table to save data for IssueLog

I made **IssueLogId** foreign key(null) inside of **CustomerNote**. Connection as you can see is 0..1 to N, therefore foreignKey can be NULL.

**Data is inserted into CustomerIssue and IssueLog** as expected, but it throws error:

> A navigation link 'CustomerNotes' was found with type 'feed', but its matching navigation property is of kind EntityReference. A navigation link with type 'feed' must match a navigation property of kind EntitySetReference.

Error happens at second SaveChanges():

```
public void AddNewCustomerIssue(HelpdeskCreateIssueModel model, int userId)
{
    if (model.CustomerIssue != null)
    {
        model.CustomerIssue.CustomerId = userId;
        model.CustomerIssue.CreatedByCustomer = userId;
        model.CustomerIssue.ModifiedByCustomer = userId;
        model.CustomerIssue.Status = 1;
        model.CustomerIssue.IsDeleted = false;
        model.CustomerIssue.IsPaused = false;

        this.ClientRepositories.ProxyDB.AddToCustomerIssues(model.CustomerIssue);
        this.ClientRepositories.ProxyDB.SaveChanges();

        // issue log
        model.IssueLog.CustomerIssueId = model.CustomerIssue.Id;
        model.IssueLog.CreatedByCustomer = userId;
        model.IssueLog.ModifiedByCustomer = userId;
        this.ClientRepositories.ProxyDB.AddToIssueLogs(model.IssueLog);
        this.ClientRepositories.ProxyDB.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Comment: What kind of exception do you got? And how is your repository designed?